# How to open an agent' view area on startup?

Tags: anylogic

how can I open an agent specific view area when enter in some agent during model execution? Alternatively setup a specific zoom level that will contains all the blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use the "onStartup" code field for Main using `myViewArea.navigateTo()`. You can set zoom levels in the view-area properties.

If you want to set a specific agent's view, you should do that in the button that navigates to that agent, using the code above (i.e. the default AnyLogic view controls at the top of your sim window will always take you to the 0,0-position).

PS: Some more useful info in my [blog post on view areas](http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/3/28/anylogic-user-interface-vol-4-the-view-area).